# How to print set from JSON array objects using Python

Tags: python, json, leaflet

Iam working python json array objects.I am trying to print first set based on condition 0<=a<=21
I have to print 'number' item.Please help me.Thank you.

```
dic1 = [{'a':4,'b':5,'number':80},{'a':10, 'b':21,'number':200}]
for i in dic1:
  if 0<=i['a']<=21:
     print(i['number'])
  elif 17<=i['b']<=34:
     print(i['number'])
```

Output I got 
80 
80
What Actually I want.
if First condition is true  output should be 
80
if second condition true output should be 
200

Comment: It looks like the "javascript" tag is not relevant to this question. (Despite its name and origin, JSON is not a JavaScript-specific standard.)

Comment: Your code works fine, getting expected results.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your script it works. If you have a large number of dictionaries then this is not a good idea. But in this case, I would use the range function as it is more convenient. See the upper limit, if you want to include 21 you have to set it to 22 in python.

## updates

based on your comment if you want the loop to be terminated after the first condition is reached, use the break statement

```
for dictionary in dic1:
    if dictionary['a'] in range(0, 21):
        print(dictionary['number'])
        break
    elif dictionary['b'] in range(17, 34):
        print(dictionary['number'])
```

Comment: thank you for helping. your script getting two set output but i want to print from first set only

Comment: you mean you only want to print first condition?

Comment: @hemanta, using range here is not necessary. What OP has done is pythonic way to check values inside boundary conditions.

Comment: @Sushanth as the two keys are different in two dictionaries, range function also does the same. Either way is fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I got results what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a break statement, loop breaks and only one of the if conditions is executed. That's how you won't get both the outputs.

```
dic1 = [{'a':4,'b':5,'number':80},{'a':10, 'b':21,'number':200}]
for i in dic1:
  if 0<=i['a']<=21:
     print(i['number'])
     break
  elif 17<=i['b']<=34:
     print(i['number'])
     break
```

Comment: Please, explain what what is the change you introduced and why it is needed, so that other people understand why the `break` works here.